# ListBox with copy paste feature

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox, copy-paste

I am using MVVM approach, my UI needs to provide a simple copy paste area (something like TextBox) to the user and once user enters the text, I need to convert all newline separated text into list items - list items because I want to highlight individual items with errors, if any.

It should be seamless for the user- user should only see List items and should be able to edit them later.

Hence, basically I need a ListBox (for the programmer) which acts like a textbox (for the user). How can I achieve this?

I have implemented this using a Grid with TextBox & ListBox in the same Row, but with some overlap so that user can paste text in textbox and as soon as user enters the text, viewmodel separates the newlines into listitems. It is working but I am facing many issues (like clearing the textbox, etc.). I am looking for better more efficient solution if any. Below is the code snippet from xaml:

```
 <Grid>
        <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Transparent"
                 Text="{Binding TextBoxData, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
            <TextBox.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding OnNewLineCommand}"/>
            </TextBox.InputBindings>
        </TextBox>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxItems}" Margin="0,20,0,0" BorderBrush="Transparent" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding}" BorderBrush="Transparent"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Thanks,

RDV

Comment: What issues? Clearing which TextBox? Sorry amigo but it sounds like you're looking for both technical and user experience consultation in one broad question.

Comment: Both are technical, refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42679395/textbox-value-changed-from-viewmodel-not-reflected-on-ui/42679907#42679907

Comment: @RDV I am somewhat with Chris, your question is a little broad. What are your specific issues? There are many ways to accomplish this, and who is to say if anything I come up with is "better" than your solution. Determining if it is better and more efficient requires better knowledge of all the requirements OR by knowing the exact 'issues' you are having. If there are specific issues you want to get rid of, or a result you would rather have, then it would be easier to assist.