# Textbox value changed from Viewmodel not reflected on UI

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties

I have a textbox, text is bound to a property in ViewModel. User can either manually enter the text or paste it from clipboard. 
I parse the text (I use **UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged**) entered by the user and split the text by newline char.

**Problem**: When user hits enter, everything works fine. But when I try to process the pasted text, as soon as I see first "\n", I try to break it into different strings and clear the textbox. In ViewModel, text is set to string.empty, but it is not reflected on the UI.

What is wrong in the code? I understand that editing the text in its own setter property is not good coding practice, but how can I do it otherwise?

Here is the code snippet:

XAML

```
    <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Transparent"
             Text="{Binding TextBoxData, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
        <TextBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding OnNewLineCommand}"/>
        </TextBox.InputBindings>
    </TextBox>
```

ViewModel:

```
     public string TextBoxData
        {
            get
            {
                return _textBoxData;
            }
            set
            {
                _textBoxData = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("TextBoxData");
                if(_textBoxData != null && _textBoxData.Contains("\n"))
                {
                    OnNewLineCommandEvent(null);
                }
            }
        }

    public DelegateCommand<string> OnNewLineCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_onNewLineCommand == null)
            {
                _onNewLineCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(OnNewLineCommandEvent);
            }
            return _onNewLineCommand;
        }
    }

    private void OnNewLineCommandEvent(string obj)
    {
        if (_textBoxData != null && _textBoxData.Length > 0)
        {
            List<string> tbVals = _textBoxData.Split('\n').ToList();
            foreach (string str in tbVals)
            {
                ListBoxItems.Add(new UnitData(str.Trim()));
            }
            TextBoxData = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Thanks,

RDV

Comment: Does your ViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Did you try calling RaisePropertyChanged after OnNewLineCommandEvent in the setter?

Comment: Yes, my VM implement INotifyPropertyChanged- it is called RaisePropertyChanged. Yes I tried calling RaisePropertyChanged after OnNewLineCommandEvent , but it didnt help either

Comment: Your code works for me exactly as it is. I don't believe in gremlins, so something must differ between your code and mine. The most common way for this type of thing to go wrong is the DataContext not being what you think it is -- and I don't have nearly enough code to know where your XAML snippet is getting its DataContext from. If you put a breakpoint in the setter for `TextBoxData`, does that definitely get hit when you type in the textbox?

Comment: This temporary change to the binding should tell you a lot, when you look at the VS Output pane at runtime: `Text="{Binding TextBoxData, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"`

Comment: Yes, this code works for me from a temp project, when I put this code in my big project things slow down (i believe). I have tried PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High and setting the debug points. DataContext is set correctly, values in VM are correct before & after OnNewLineCommandEvent - only issue is what is shown on the UI.

Comment: Hmm...are you saying that the code works or doesn't work?

Comment: this code works when i have a very small project, when i put this piece of code in a big project (which has lot more UI elements), this 'exact' same code doesn't work.

Comment: Let's start with the assumption that there's something specific in the big project that's causing a specific problem. If "things slowed down" to the point where event handlers are never called, I hardly think the application would be usable at all. Did you try the binding trace in the big project? In the big project, if you give the `TextBoxData` a default value ("Blah blah" or some such), does that value appear in the text box initially?

Comment: yes, I tried putting the initial value ("XYZ"), it takes it. I tweaked my code a little an now it is working. I am posting the answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, my other solution worked only the first time, but because of your last comment of adding something initially i figured out the issue- for textbox if text value is not changing, it is not reflected on the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. If I try to modify textbox value within its setter and value is not changed, it is not reflected on the UI. Below might help explain this better:

1. Initially, when the UI starts textbox value in VM is set to "ABC".
2. User changes this value to "XYZ" from the UI.
3. In the VM setter, programmer checks if textbox value is "XYZ", then change it back to "ABC" --> This was failing in my case. The value of textbox in VM was changed to "ABC" but UI would still show "XYZ".

Solution: In VM, instead of setting value back to "ABC" set it to "ABC " (Notice the additional space) -> this will change the UI value.

Updated VM Code:

```
        private bool _isTextValChanged = false;
    private void OnNewLineCommandEvent(string obj)
    {
        if (_textBoxData != null && _textBoxData.Length > 0)
        {
            List<string> tbVals = _textBoxData.Split('\n').ToList();
            foreach (string str in tbVals)
            {
                ListBoxItems.Add(new UnitData(str.Trim()));
            }
            //This will toggle textbox value and updated value will be reflected on the UI.
            if (_isTextValChanged)
                TextBoxData = " ";
            else
                TextBoxData = string.Empty;

            _isTextValChanged = !_isTextValChanged;
        }
    }
```

Thanks,

RDV